# Goole Auth and Facebook Auth problem with firebase and chrome extension

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I'm building a Chrome Extension with VueJS, in this extension I have 3 buttons to connect a user, Google, Facebook and Email/Password. The third system Email/Password works very fine and I can submit user to my dataBase, but when I click on the Google of Facebook button, I have an error in my console and I don't known what this is, knowing that I have followed all the steps that the Google document advises us to do to create those 2 authentication popup (even in the manifest.json folder).

There is the error :

```
code: "auth/unauthorized-domain" 
message: "This chrome extension ID (chrome-extension://myID) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign
```

There is my manifest.json

```js
{
  "name": "extension",
  "description": "VueJS Extension",
  "version": null,
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/logo.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "extension",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "identity"
  ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "myAppID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://apis.google.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

And there is my `signup.vue` component :

```js
methods: {
    googleSignIn() {
        let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        console.log(provider);
        fb.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result)
                console.log("Account success")
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.$router.push({
                    name: 'main'
                })
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err)
                console.log(("Account failed"))
            })
    },

    facebookSignIn() {
        let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        console.log(provider);
        fb.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result)
                console.log("Account success")
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.$router.push({
                    name: 'main'
                })
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err)
                console.log(("Account failed"))
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you successfully used firebase facebook login with chrome extension? I have problem with facebook app cant have chrome-extension:.. in App Domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your chrome extension ID in the Firebase Console Authentication section -> Sign-in method -> Authorized domains

You will need to add your chrome extension ID. It will have the form:
`chrome-extension://myID`

Comment: Yes I have add my chome-extension ID, its weird.

Comment: @coco_282 did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes I have thanks a lot ! sorry for the late response I've forgot to answer ;)

Comment: @coco_282 Any hints on the possible solution. Have also asked a similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040133/google-sign-in-with-firebase-for-chrome-extension-in-react